# Pandas : Updating multiple column in a dataframe based on values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, updating

I have two dataframes of different dimensions. 
I need to update msg_count in df1 from `df2` only if column value[UserId,Month] of `df1` and `df2` matches

My data is as follows:

```
df1:
UserID  Month           A       B       C       D       E       F  msg_count

knaas    1/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0  
knaas    2/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    3/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    4/1/2017       0       0       0       2       0       0    0
knaas    5/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    6/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    7/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    8/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    9/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    10/1/2017      0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    11/1/2017      0       0       0       0       0       0    0
knaas    12/1/2017      0       0       0       0       0       0    0
ArtCort0324 1/1/2017    0       0       0       0       0       0    0 
ArtCort0324 2/1/2017    0       2       0       2       0       0    0 
ArtCort0324 3/1/2017    0       0       0       0       0       0    0 
ArtCort0324 4/1/2017    0       1       1       0       0       0    0
ArtCort0324 5/1/2017    0       0       0       3       0       0    0
ArtCort0324 6/1/2017    0       0       0       0       0       0    9 

df2:
  UserID           Month    msg_count       
  ArtCort0324   1/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   2/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   3/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   4/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   5/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   6/1/2017    9    
  ArtCort0324   7/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   8/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   9/1/2017    0    
  ArtCort0324   10/1/2017   0     
  ArtCort0324   11/1/2017   0    
  ArtCort0324   12/1/2017   0
```

I have tried the following code snippets. But it didn't work as expected

```
res = df2.set_index(['UserID', 'Month'])\
     .combine_first(df1.set_index(['UserID', 'Month']))\
     .reset_index()

updated_new = df1.merge(gitter, how='left', on=['UserID', 'Month'], 
suffixes=('', '_new'))
 updated_new['msg_count'] = 
 np.where(pd.notnull(updated_new['msg_count_new']), 
 updated_new['msg_count_new'], updated_new['msg_count'])
```

I need the output as below

```
UserID  Month           A       B       C       D       E       F  msg_count

knaas   1/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   2/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   3/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   4/1/2017        0       0       0       2       0       0     0    
knaas   5/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   6/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   7/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   8/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   9/1/2017        0       0       0       0       0       0     0     
knaas   10/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   11/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
knaas   12/1/2017       0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
ArtCort0324  1/1/2017   0       0       0       0       0       0     0    
ArtCort0324  2/1/2017   1       0       0       0       0       0     0    
ArtCort0324  3/1/2017   0       0       0       0       0       0     50    
ArtCort0324  4/1/2017   0       0       0       0       0       0     0
```

I have added a default column `msg_count` to `df1` with default value 0.
I need to update the `msg_count` from `df1` with value of `msg_count` from `df2`, only if `UserId` and `Month` are equal in both dataframes

Comment: Please, could you paste the data in a well formatted way and as a `pd.DataFrame()`  call for easier testing?

Comment: What colums of `df2` do you mean by `col3`, `col4`? I do not see it even from the wanted result. There is still no way of copy-pasting the data into my Jupyter notebook. Please, add `pd.DataFrame` creation call from a dict or something for `df1` and `df2`.

Comment: Hi @Ronald Luc, were you able to copy the data.

Comment: Now I understand what you want, but the examples are not consistent with your description: 
Where did `ArtCort0324  3/1/2017   0       0       0       0       0       0     50` get `msg_count == 50`?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a `merge`:

```
df_merge = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, on=['UserID', 'Month'], how='left']
```

You may want to set how as `'inner', 'outer'`, etc...

Comment: Great very specific feedback